# Reading and writing an array in a file using C functions in cython

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, cython

I am instantiating a class in **cython**. I want to declare one of the instance which is an array of `float` values once by computing it with a given function and save it in a binary file using **c** functions. For the further call of my class if the input file does already exist, the instance would be declared by reading the array from the file otherwise it would compute it again.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

from libc.stdio cimport FILE, fopen, fwrite, fscanf, fclose, fseek, SEEK_END, ftell, stdout, stderr
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double exp(double) nogil
    double log(double) nogil

cdef class Hit(object):
    cdef public double[::1] zs, Da
    cdef char* path

    def __cinit__(self, zs=None, path=None):
        if path is None:
           raise ValueError("Could not find a path to the file which contains the table of distances")
        else:
           self.path=path
        if zs is None:
           raise ValueError("You must give an array which contains the steps!")
        self.zs=zs
        cdef Py_ssize_t i, N
        N=len(self.zs)
        cdef FILE *ptr_fr
        cdef FILE *ptr_fw
        cdef double[::1] ptr_d = np.empty((N,))
        ptr_fr = fopen(self.path, "rb")
        ptr_fw = fopen(self.path, "wb")
        if (ptr_fr==NULL):
           print "I/O Error: cannot open file {}".format( self.path)  
           for i from N > i >= 0:
               ptr_d[i]=log(self.zs[i]+1.) /(1- self.zs[i])**0.5    
           if (ptr_fw == NULL):
               print "Unable to open file!\n"
           else:
               print "Opened file successfully for writing.\n"
               fwrite(<void*>&ptr_d[0], sizeof(double), N, ptr_fw)
               fclose(ptr_fw)
               self.Da = ptr_d

        else: 
           for i from N > i >= 0:
               fscanf(ptr_fr,"%f", &ptr_d[i])

           fclose(ptr_fr)
           self.Da = ptr_d
```

When I run my code for the second time the values that returns from reading a file to a pointer is correct, however I think the way I allocated the pointer to a memoryview has a problem since all the values in `self.Da` instance are zeros. Any suggestion ?!!

Comment: As a side note: Do you really want to do that? Cython is a great tool when you would like to speed up time critical code or interface with external C code. For everything else normal python is probably a much better choice. as it is less error prone and much more readable.

Comment: @cel It is a small part of my code which is written in cython. I need to access to this array as fast as possible if it has been computed once. I tried with python I/O functions. I think using c and binary file would be the fastest option.

Comment: One small point: scanf needs "%lf" when reading doubles (this is different to printf!).

Comment: Also, is it worth looking at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html (and related) numpy functions for loading and saving your data. They should be both quick and painless (and do the whole array in one go)

Comment: @DavidW I updated my question and I used pointer, but there is problem where I assigned the value of the pointer to memortview.

Comment: I didn't recommend using pointers to store your data! That seems a much more difficult way of doing things than using numpy arrays. Unfortunatly I don't have a computer with Cython on infront of me so I don't think I can help further. I'm a little surprised Christian's answer didn't work though.

Comment: @DavidW the problems seems to be when the file in `path` doesn't exist previously. My answer works when the file is previously created. I'm looking why it is still not working in all cases.

Comment: Actually - one further thought: fscanf makes no sense for binary files, right?

Comment: fscanf reads from the stream and stores in the format you put. I wouldn't say that it doesn't make sens, but you have to be careful that you always know the format of the data you are reading.

Comment: @DavidW I have fixed the bug of writing and reading an array to a file. It works perfectly now. On the other hand, the way I allocate the pointer to a memoryview still has a problem because the values in `self.Da` are almost zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to my own question is:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libc.stdio cimport FILE, fopen, fwrite, fscanf, fclose, fprintf, fseek, ftell, SEEK_END, rewind, fread
from numpy cimport float64_t
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double exp(double) nogil
    double log(double) nogil

cdef class Hit(object):
    cdef public double[::1] zs,  Da
    cdef char* path

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.cdivision(True)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.nonecheck(False)
    def __cinit__(self, path=None, zs=None):
        if path is None:
           raise ValueError("Could not find a path to the file which contains the table of distances")
        else:
           self.path=path

        if zs is None:
           raise ValueError("You must give an array which contains the steps!")
        self.zs=zs

        cdef Py_ssize_t i, N, lSize
        N=len(np.ascontiguousarray(self.zs))
        print "Input file should have ",N
        cdef FILE *ptr_fr
        cdef FILE *ptr_fw
        cdef size_t result
        cdef double *ptr_d= <double *>malloc(N * sizeof(double))
        ptr_fr = fopen(self.path, "rb")        
        if (ptr_fr==NULL):
           print "I/O Error: cannot open file {}".format( self.path) 
           for i from N > i >= 0:
               ptr_d[i]=log(self.zs[i])
               print ptr_d[i]
           ptr_fw = fopen(self.path, "wb")
           if (ptr_fw == NULL):
               print "Unable to open file!\n"

           else:

               print "Opened file successfully for writing.\n"
               fwrite(ptr_d, sizeof(double), N, ptr_fw)
               fclose(ptr_fw)
               self.Da = np.asarray(<double[:N]>ptr_d)
        else: 
           fseek (ptr_fr , 0 , SEEK_END)
           lSize = ftell (ptr_fr)
           print lSize
           rewind (ptr_fr)
           result=fread(ptr_d,sizeof(double),lSize ,ptr_fr )
           for i from N > i >= 0:
               print ptr_d[i]
           fclose(ptr_fr)
           self.Da = np.asarray(<double[:N]>ptr_d)
        print np.ascontiguousarray(self.Da)

        free(ptr_d)
```

Comment: Glad you found your answer; I tried mine and it didn't crash on my PC so I couldn't be any hel beyond that point. (it used the first version, with memoryviews insted of pointers).

Comment: @ CristiánAntuña I don't know exactly why it crashed! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You should change your line:

```
ptr_fw = fopen(self.path, "wb")
```

For

```
ptr_fw = fopen(self.path, "ab")
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

> [w option] write: Create an empty file for output operations. If a file with the same name already exists, its contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file.

While

> [a option] append: Open file for output at the end of a file. Output operations always write data at the end of the file, expanding it. Repositioning operations (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) are ignored. The file is created if it does not exist.

The brackets are mine. You were deleting the content in `path` once you opened it. So the next time, you opened an empty file.

**UPDATE:** (I did both of these changes on your first implementation)

Plus, change your

```
fwrite(<void*>&ptr_d[0], sizeof(double), N, ptr_fw)
```

for:

```
       for i in range(N):
           fprintf(ptr_fw, "%lf\n", ptr_d[N-i-1])
```

You were reading formated but writting unformatted (remember to cimport fprintf from stdio, and the change above is also important).

Comment: Or move it to after "if ptr_fr==NULL:". This is obviously the right answer though.

Comment: @CristiánAntuña there is something wrong with the way I use `fwrite` for the pointer. Because the file are basically empty even I used your answer. Moreover, I am not sure the way I allocated a pointer to a memoryview is correct or not?!!

Comment: @CristiánAntuña The code crashed with the change you have suggested in the updated answer.  The error  is:`*** glibc detected *** python: free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x000000000104ddc0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7db26)[0x7fb6501d7b26]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x155)[0x7fb6501c77a5]
./Test.so(+0x182a1)[0x7fb64ef862a1]
./Test.so(+0x19e48)[0x7fb64ef87e48]
`